# Pushing into multiple remote repositories simultaneously in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using git within the [IntelliJ IDEA IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). I have two remote repositories to which I would like to push my commits. How do I push to both remotes simultaneously?

Comment: Have you tried defining a remote with multiple urls?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas Can you do that from within IDEA? If yes, how?

Comment: @TheJeed I'm not sure about the UI for IDEA, but if you configure the git remote to have multiple URLs via command line jgit or whatever driver they use should respect that.

Answer (score 8):

There is a nice [blog post](https://www.xenovation.com/blog/source-control-management/git/push-code-into-two-git-remote-repositories) which explains how to do this with IntelliJ. 
It does however not allow for simultaneous push to 2 repositories.

I will shorten the blog content (and copy past the authors text).

1. Add a second remote repository

Let’s assume we’re working on the code from repository1, already imported to IntelliJ.
Add another remote repository, we’ll call it repository2.

```
In the menu, go to VCS→ Git → Remotes…
```

[image: add remote menu item]

2. Copy the link of the repository2 by going to your GitLab (I was using BitBucket), selecting your project, clicking on Clone, and copying the URL.

[image: BitBucket clone repository]

3. Click on a plus, name the remote (eg. origin-copy, in my case work-in-progress) and provide the link to the repository2. Click OK.

[image: remote dialog]

4. You should now see the new repository – repository2 added to the list of Git remotes
5. In the menu, go to VSC → Git → Fetch. This way you make sure you have access to all the repository2 branches.
6. Git commit and push
   Push the current repository1 branch to repository2 branch:

   Press Ctrl+shift+k (or go to VSC → Git → Push…)

[image: git push]

Select the repository you’d like to push your code to. For example, if your repository1 is named origin and repository2 is named origin-copy, select origin-copy. After that you can also select the branch you’d like to push your code to by clicking on the name of the branch (it will autocomplete the name of the branch as you type it in). You can also type in a name of a new branch, which will be then automatically created in the repository2.

7. When you’re done with selecting the repository (we named repository2 origin-copy) and the branch we want to push to (in our case develop) you can press the button Push.

Comment: Is there a way to select a different remote using the keyboard exclusively?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good example it worked for me

> ...
>
> For example, here are the remotes specified in my .git/config file:

```
[remote "origin"] 
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* 
  url = /Users/loki/sandbox/git/parent 
[remote "github"] 
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* 
  url = git@github.com:jbklikh/git_test.git
```

> ...

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206722225-how-to-specify-multiple-remote-repositories

Answer (score 2):

```
modify .git/config add mirror code...
 [core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://JungleYang@192.168.10.96:18080/r/upflow.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = http://JungleYang@192.168.10.189:18080/r/upflow.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/mirror/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```