# How to configure "update project" in Intellij to pull from an upstream repository and push to a fork?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, git-fork

I'm using Intellij to pull from an `upstream` repository, make changes locally and push to my fork (`origin`). I understand how this can be done by doing a fetch, correctly configured pull and then correctly configured push.

My concern is that there are multiple manual steps here. Is there a way to configure Intellij's 'Update Project' operation to have different default repositories to update from (fetch & pull) and push to? Currently 'Update Project' operation just updates from the current repository and it's easy to forget to update from `upstream`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to configure Intellij's 'Update Project' operation to have different default repositories to update from (fetch & pull) and push to?

No: [IDEA-100429](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100429) is about considering a `push.default` value, and is still unresolved:

> 2020 calling. This remains very annoying for triangular workflow (separate `@{push}` and `@{upstream}`) where I can use IntelliJ to multi-branch, multi-commit across projects but need to go into each one and do a "`git push`" which (with no further config) knows what to do where IntelliJ mistakenly tries to push to `@{upstream}` instead of honoring the `git config`.

And [IDEA-98693](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98693) mentions Git Push dialog does not remember remote branch, but:

> Remembering the previous branch you pushed to is bad because among other:
>
> Any branch you push to will be remembered and you accidentally could bush to a wrong branch next time, if e.g. you need to push a branch somewhere only once and then push to the upstream/tracked branch again.
>
> The better approach is to set defaults. It is tracked branch by default, but if it does not work - configure git accordingly.
>
> Remembering branch is useful sometimes, but is not in other cases - there are requests to allow setting default branch to push.
>
> `git push` behaves differently.
>
> So we reverted the behavior! 2018.1 and further will not remember the last branch but will behave like git push on the commSo and line.
> So by default, it will select a branch depending on your `git config` settings.
>
> So if you want to push to some specific branches (different from default upstream) specify e.g
>
> ```
> git config remote.<name>.push refs/heads/LocalBranch:refs/heads/remoteBranch
> ```

For a practical example, see "[Pushing into multiple remote repositories simultanously in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58960346/6309)". (it works at least for pushing to a different remote repo)